# Hide and Show DIV using strict javascript with no embedded JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched and searched over so many previously answered questions and to my surprise, NONE of them answer what I am trying to accomplish. with JQuery this is easy but I am struggling with strict javascript.

I cannot have any embedded JS OR CSS in the html...

This is what I have so far:

```
function showhide()
{
    var billingaddress = document.getElementById("billingaddress");
    if (billingaddress.style.display === "block")
        {
            billingaddress.style.display = "none";
        }
    else if (billingaddress.style.display === "none")
        {
            billingaddress.style.display = "block";
        }
}

function init () 
{   
    var billingcheckbox = document.getElementById("billing");

    if (billingcheckbox.checked)
        {
            showhide();
        } 
    else 
        {
            showhide();
        }
```

It is hidden by default using CSS.

Cheers,

Comment: _"hidden by default using CSS"_ --- how is it hidden?

Comment: Also, re-querying the `billingaddress` is a waste. Instead pass it as a parameter to `showhide`.

Comment: using the css #billingaddress{
    display: none;
}

Comment: Then what's the problem? Apart from your `init` function missing a closing brace.

Comment: well I have a bit more code below that I didn't include because that is fine and working... Its that my div does not show or hide when I click the checkbox. it is always hidden... nothing changes.. All other functions work within the js file

Comment: That's not what you've implied in the question. Assuming `init` only runs once, `billingaddress` will only hide/show on first run. There's no code in the example which runs when the checkbox changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With he code you've provided, it can be done like this.

`billingaddress.style.display` is empty by default, you can easily check it in the if without a comparison.

```js
function showhide() {
  if (billingaddress.style.display) billingaddress.style.display = ""
  else billingaddress.style.display = 'none';
}

var billingaddress = document.getElementById("billingaddress")
var billingcheckbox = document.getElementById("billing")
billingcheckbox.addEventListener('change', showhide)
billingcheckbox.checked = true
showhide()
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="billing"/> Hide
<div id="billingaddress">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Any reason to not use `addEventListener`?

Comment: but isnt using the onchange="showhide()" embedding Javascript?

Comment: I'll try an addEventListener... see how I go

Comment: @Jonathan sorry, I was a bit to eager to post this answer. I made an update

Comment: @arcs mate you are a legend. all i did was set the billingcheckbox.checked = false. as thats the default I wanted it. but now it works like a charm. you legend!

Comment: @Jonathan glad to help

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as this:

this keyword inside event handler references checkbox element so you can get checkbox state with this.checked property.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="billing">
<input type="text" id="billingaddress" placeholder="Address" style="display:none">
<script>
  var billingAddress = document.getElementById("billingaddress");
  var billingCheckbox = document.getElementById("billing");

  billingCheckbox.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    billingAddress.style.display = this.checked ? "block" : "none";
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do it -- but to be sure make sure all your IDs are matching up with what is in the HTML markup:

```
function showhide(show) {   

    var billingaddress = document.getElementById("billingaddress"); 

    if (show) { 

        billingaddress.style.display = "block"; 

    } else {    

        billingaddress.style.display = "none";
    }
}   

function init () {   

    var billingcheckbox = document.getElementById("billing");   

    if (billingcheckbox.checked) {  

        showhide(true); 

    } else {    

        showhide(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: just tried it. sorry mate it didn't work. I tried something like that earlier and it didn't work either. mr ARCS above got it working spot on.

Comment: Ah I think having an event handler/listener is what's missing in my solution. Glad you got it working! Thanks for the update :)